# MySQL insert query gives the error MYSQL has gone away

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the error `MYSQL has gone away` during my insert query, Even i don't know if it is possible or not to insert approximate 7000 new records in a single insert query.

```
insert into table name (col1, col2, col3, ....) 
values 
    ('col1', 'col2', 'col3', ....), 
    ('col1', 'col2', 'col3', ....), 
    ('col1', 'col2', 'col3', ....) .....
```

I also set the following configuration in mysqld : `max_allowed_packet = 512M` and

```
// php.ini
mysql.connect_timeout = 300
default_socket_timeout = 300
```

Can anyone please guide me to resolve this problem?

Comment: It's definitely possible.  You should be looking at wait_timeout as you're already connected. max_allowed_packed is probably high enough.  Are you using persistent connections perchance?  Try using `mysql_ping` to verify connectivity _before_ starting a long query.

Comment: @DanFarrell you means i have to find out how do i call the mysql_ping with PDO, I am suing codeigniter for this.

Comment: @jogesh_pi why not use prepared statement and insert records that will certainly be faster and without errors. As in this case if sometime 7500 records came instead of 7000 it can again halt your script.

Comment: @LoneWOLFs I have changed my method to insert data, because the length of data could be anything, so i decided to insert data into chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (!mysql_ping ($conn)) {
   //here is the major trick, you have to close the connection (even though its not currently working) for it to recreate properly.
   mysql_close($conn);
   $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass');
   mysql_select_db('db',$conn);
}
```

ref :http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-ping.php

Answer (score 0):

try this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html it has possible causes available for this.may be you are running a long operation and you 300 ms are also not sufficient for this. or

you can set

```
 $pdo->exec("SET @@session.wait_timeout = {$waitTimeout}");
```